# Identifying this font

Tags: font-identification

Can someone help me identify the following font please? Finding it a bit tricky with the free website recognition systems out there because it is a type of scripting

[image]

Comment: It's too small an image for automatic font recognition systems. Have you nothing larger?

Comment: No I'm afraid not, just doing this for a friend

Comment: Sadly then there is nothing for it but to go through the thousand of script-like fonts that are out there, and see if you can find one that matches, or is close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Signalist from MyFonts:

[image]

It was found by separating some glyphs to a sparse formation and inputting them to FontSquirrel Matcherator.

The identification string used:

[image]

It was enlargened to 400% with ON1 resizer and tresholded to BW before uploading